# Android: Is there an onSMSSend event?

Tags: android, sms

I've got an idea for an Android Application, however I am unsure if it would work. Essentially what I want to do is "intercept" all text messages sent from any SMS App and make modifications to them.

For example, say I write out the following SMS:

```
Hi {Name}, how are you today? Can you tell {Boss} I'll be 15 minutes late today.
```

The onSMSSend function in my application(assuming it is currently running in the background) would then be able to edit the content of the message(Eg. Replacing variables with ones defined in the application), and then send it on to the recipient.

Is Android able to provide this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not. Android may be able to inform you after an SMS was send. But there is no way to intercept a message that should be sent and apply changes to it on a non rooted phone.

What you could do is to write a new messaging App that allows the user to type a message, choose a number and send the message. Now you have full control over the message that is send but building a replacement for the sms app is a fair amount of work.

Comment: Assuming the phone was rooted, how would this be achieved?

Comment: I'm so glad that this is impossible. This would be a major security issue. For the purpose Peter-W mentions it seems ok, but imagine how much damage could be done by manipulating messages.. @Peter-W: Is it really necessary to work with every SMS-App? Why don't you build one for yourself?

Comment: Maybe rooting is not enough to achieve this. It would need either doing changes on the original message app or on the system parts that sends the message.

Comment: @Stefan security is not so much bothering me, the possibility to attach spam to every message sent from a phone would be much more useful to a person filling a phone with malware...

Comment: @stefan: Yes, security reasons are why I assumed it would be not possible, it's not something I would like random apps doing. In regards to building my own SMS-App I was hoping to add extra functionality to everyone, by building a whole application mine must outperform over alternatives in every way in order for people to use it. I wouldn't change my SMS-App for a small feature like this.

Comment: @Janusz: Do you know if the vanilla messaging app is Open Source?

Comment: @Peter-W It should be in the Android Repository